# Find recent files in directory with Bash

Tags: bash, file

I want to write a Bash script to look for a new file (recently added file) in a folder and output the name of the new file (including the file type, i.e. example.png) to a variable.

How would I do it?

Comment: `man find` and depending on your definition of _new file_ look for `-atime`, `-ctime`, `-mtime`, `-amin`, `-cmin` or `-mmin`.

Comment: Define _new file_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
find . -mmin -10
```

This command recursively finds all the files and directories in the current folder that have been modified/created in the past 10 minutes.

`-mmin` stands for minutes. You can also use `-mtime` which counts days. In addition you can use a `+` in front of the given number which makes `find` search for files that have been created/modified at least the given amount of time ago.

If you intend to further parse and use the output, which I assume you do because you intend to store it in a variable, you shouldn't use `ls` as it optimized for presentation and can change its output format depending on where you write to.

Comment: This just outputs a .

Comment: it searches the current folder recursively. you are probably running it in a folder that doesn't cover the condition of having files which have been modified/created in the last 10 minutes

Comment: I am, I moved a file into the folder and then ran the command

Comment: moving a file does not change its creation/modification date. `mmin` changes when file's data changes. maybe you are looking for the `cmin` flag. this works when the status of the files changes, which does when you move a file

Comment: Okay yeah cmin is exactly what I was looking for
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to use the `-t` option of `ls`:

```sh
ls -t
```

From `man ls`:

```
 --sort=WORD
        sort  by  WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S), time
        (-t), version (-v), extension (-X)

 --time=WORD
        change the default of  using  modification  times;  access
        time  (-u):  atime,  access, use; change time (-c): ctime,
        status; birth time: birth, creation;

        with  -l,  WORD  determines  which  time  to  show;   with
        --sort=time, sort by WORD (newest first)

 --time-style=TIME_STYLE
        time/date format with -l; see TIME_STYLE below

 -t     sort by time, newest first; see --time
```